# Is there software that will completely wipe your Android device when there are too many pin attempts?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, security, tablet, motorola-moto-g, nook-hd

I love the option that your iPhone will wipe itself if someone preforms way to many pin attempts but I do not see that option on Android devices. Is there software that will completely wipe your Android device when there are too many pin attempts?